# Building python-cryptography with LibreSSL on Windows

Tags: python, windows, cryptography, libressl

I'd like to build [cryptography](http://cryptography.io) module for Python 3.5 on Windows 7 x64 with Visual Studio 2015 and link it to LibreSSL. I tried to follow the guide in the docs for manual builds and have set INCLUDE and LIB to appropriate LibreSSL dirs. But I'm getting syntax errors regarding (unexpectedly) LibreSSL headers. Previously I was able to build LibreSSL on the same machine without problems.

Building log: http://pastie.org/private/p3rakrxljcgugttc2yg5q (in Developer Command Prompt)

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Could you include (some of) the error messages? You can use the "edit" link below your question to edit them into your post.

Comment: My bad, updated the original post.

Comment: This isn't the right place for this. Speaking as a developer on the project, file an issue and someone will help you out.